# $f\in L^1_{\textrm{loc}}(U)$ with $ \int_Ufg\ dx=0 $ for every $g\in C_c^\infty(U)$ implies $f=0$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

> Suppose $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$ is a <s>measurable</s> [Edited: locally integrable] function such that
>   $$
> \int_Ufg\ dx=0,\quad \textrm{for every } g\in C_c^\infty(U).
> $$
>    Then $f=0$ a.e.

---

Suppose otherwise $f\neq 0$ on some measurable subset $V$ of $U$ such that $V$ has positive Lebesgue measure. To get a contradiction, how shall I handle the sign of $f$ on $V$?

[Added:] Could anyone come up with a handy theorem that gives the above proposition?

---

[Added:] This argument is used in the proof of uniqueness of weak derivatives in Evans's Partial Differential Equations:
[image]

Comment: If you happen to know that continuous functions are dense in $L^1$ then you may conclude if $f$ is locally integrable?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh, would you elaborate your comment?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh's answer is correct, but you'll need to fill in some technical details (why it suffices to show that $\int_R f=0$ for $R\subset U$ a bounded rectangle, how to use the dominated convergence theorem, etc.). I believe Folland's Real Analysis fills out these details.

Comment: @Jack In fact, if you tell what theorems are available (notably regarding approximations) to you this allows to tailor more precisely the answer.

Answer (score 3):

When $f$ is locally integrable it suffices to show that $\int_R f=0$ for all bounded rectangles in $U$. Now there is a sequence $\psi_n \in C_c^\infty(R)$, $0\leq \psi_n\leq 1$ that converges to $1_R$ pointwise a.e.  So by dominated convergence
  $$ 0 = \int \psi_n f \rightarrow \int_R f $$

We used (among other things) that if ${\cal A}$ is a subalgebra (here the rectangles) that generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra then the set of step functions over ${\cal A}$ is dense in $L^1(U)$.

More details on algebras: The set ${\cal R}$ consisting of finite union of rectangles form an algebra (it is stable under finite intersections, unions and differences). Any open set in ${\Bbb R}^n$ is a countable union of such. It follows that the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing ${\cal R}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Given a fixed rectangle $R$ and a measurable subset $Y\subset R$ we can find a sequence of step maps $\phi_n$ over ${\cal R}$ (i.e. sum of characteristic functions over rectangles) that converge a.e. (and in $L^1$) to $\chi_Y$. Repeating the above argument we conclude that $\int_Y f=0$ (for a proof regarding this approximation sequence, see e.g. Serge Lang, Real and Functional Analysis, section IV, corollary 6.4; or other books on integration theory).

Comment: I don't see how $\psi_n\to 1_R$ in $L^1$ implies what you say it does. Now if you'd said just that $\psi_n\to1_R$ _pointwise_ things would be fine... (assuming as well that all the $\psi_n$ are supported in some fixed compact set).

Comment: Thanks, the compact is simply $R$ as already stated.

Comment: Right. My main concern was not the support, rather that it seems to me you should be saying $\psi_n\to1_R$ pointwise instead of in $L^1$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich   Yes, I sort of guessed. Just didn't phrase my response well. We agree ;-) It is the easiest path.

Comment: Also, $f$ locally integrable follows from the assumption the integrals $\int_Ufg$ are defined.

Comment: Indeed, that's a point in favor!

Comment: @H.H.Rugh: Thank you very much for your answer. Would you elaborate the part "it suffices to show that $\int_Rf=0$ for all bounded rectangles in $U$"? I guess this is what the last paragraph says, but I don't know why the density of step functions over $\mathcal{A}$ in $L^1(U)$ is related.